# Wrapping packet information

Tags: c#, design-patterns, interface

I am developing a network application and therefor need to specify the packets I want to send. I have a basic interfaces class and one for the packets that implement them.

```
public interface IPacket
{
}

public interface IServerPacket : IPacket
{
}

public interface IServerChatPacket : IServerPacket
{
    ServerChatPacketType Type { get; }
}

public interface IServerAccountPacket : IServerPacket
{
    ServerAccountPacketType Type { get; }
}
```

The specification of an `IServerPacket` is needed for easier and faster serialization. Anyways, now I can use these sub-interfaces for chat server and account communication with the connected clients.

```
[Serializable]
public struct ServerChatIncomingMessagePacket : IServerChatPacket
{
    public readonly string text;

    public ServerChatPacketType
    {
        get { return ServerChatPacketType.IncomingMessage; }
    }

    public ServerChatIncomingMessagePacket(string text)
    {
        this.text = text;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public struct ServerAccountAnswerLoginPacket : IServerAccountPacket
{
    public readonly bool success;

    public ServerAccountPacketType
    {
        get { return ServerAccountPacketType.AnswerLogin; }
    }

    public ServerAccountAnswerLoginPacket(bool success)
    {
        this.success = success;
    }
}
```

Is this the right way to do it? Currently I really have no problems with this, but maybe I am using the interfaces or structs wrong? I am not new into C# or OOP but there may be some way that solves this in a different manner or with better performance (structs have a chance to hold much data which is unpractical for this type kind)?

Comment: I had an answer 3/4 typed when I realized that the code you posted is broken (and likely hypothetical). You can't define scope in an interface. Please read through our [help] and post your real, working, code in the future.

Comment: My mistake yes, because I didnt have the code files I rewrote them from my memories. But it is not hypothetical, works and therefor I think that putting this thread as off-topic is really not needed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One empty interface could be considered a code smell, but can sometimes be useful for reflection purposes. Having two is nonsensical. An interface defines a contract that the type has to adhere to. Where's the contract here? I fail to see how these two types belong to the same inheritance tree. "Type" members also set off alarm bells in my head. They're usually an indication that there are missing interfaces. You could then just inspect the actual type, if you really had to.

I would go with something more like this.

```
public interface IMessagePacket 
{
    string Message { get; }
}

public interface IStatusPacket
{
    bool Status { get; }
}

[Serializable]
public struct ServerChatIncomingMessagePacket : IMessagePacket
{
    public readonly string text;

    public string Message
    {
        get { return text; }
    }

    public ServerChatIncomingMessagePacket(string text)
    {
        this.text = text;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public struct ServerAccountAnswerLoginPacket : IStatusPacket
{
    public readonly bool success;

    public bool Status
    {
         get { return success; }
    }

    public ServerAccountAnswerLoginPacket(bool success)
    {
        this.success = success;
    }
}
```

This allows us to define *behavior* of the types. We could easily implement an `OutGoingMessagePacket` that implements `IMessagePacket`, or a `LogOffPacket` that implements `IStatusPacket`.

---

On another note, in your original implementation, you never used the parameter you passed to `ServerAccountAnswerLoginPacket`'s constructor, or it's related private readonly field.

Comment: Generally the use case for empty interfaces I see is generic type constraints. Whether or not you agree with that is a matter of debate, I guess, but I'm not sure why two interfaces (in an inheritance hierarchy) is any worse for that than one

Comment: @BenAaronson what benefit does the second empty interface add? The first one *might* be useful as a type constraint, or for reflection, but the second adds no value as far as I can tell. That's all. There might be some value to it in the real code, but OP didn't give us his real code. I wouldn't have answered at all had I noticed it sooner, because of... well... this. =)

Comment: The empty interfaces are more or less needed because in the sender/receiver service classes I can then specify the packets you are able to send with generic parameters. And I dont know if using individual interfaces for every struct would be productive for me personally, because the enum type implemented in every packet is used by my processing service for received packets. If I know leave away this enum I need to check the packet type through the "is" keyword which creates performance problems on the long run. Anyways thanks for the information.

Comment: @DoctorNiklas 1) that's the problem with not providing your real code for review. 2) consider a case where you want to create a packet that has both a message *and* a status. The way I showed here doesn't result in a 1:1 interface to struct ratio. You could implement either or both interfaces to accomplish this.

Comment: This is my real code, stuff I dont show is not needed for review. But you already stated that empty interfaces are not good which is good to know. But putting a thread as off-topic because of two little scope mistakes is unnecessary.

Comment: @RubberDuck Well, one marker interface can constrain a generic to a subset of all Types. Another marker interface can constrain a different generic to a subset of the first one. Though I agree we can't actually tell if there's any useage from the posted code.

Comment: @DoctorNiklas that's not why we put it on hold. We put it on hold because it was broken. I see you fixed the interfaces, so I'll gladly cast my vote to reopen.